# C++ Class addition method

Tags: c++, methods

I have a C++ class that primarily contains an integer and I wish to ceate a method that adds two of them together, I dont want to overload the + operator.

I belive I have 2 options:

```
var_result = var1.add(var2);

var_result.add(var1, var2);
```

where var_result, var1 and var2 are of the same type.

I think the 1st one is more intuitive ot use, but the seccond one is not creating an instance which might give performance benefits. How should I go about making this decision? This is going to be directly visible to others using my code.

I realize I might be dicing with the "opinion based" closure of this question but hopefully there is some degree of objectivity here.

Comment: I would opt for `var_result = some_namespace::add(var1, var2);`, or, make `add` an increment, so `var1.add(var2);` adds `var2` to `var1`, modifying `var1`. Or both.

Comment: Do you want your result to be an integer or a new instance of your class?

Comment: @Logicrat a new instance of the class, sorry, I should have been clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write you `add()` method with the same (preferred) semantics used for `operator+` : write a free method that returns a new object by value.

**Example :**

```
var_result = add(var1, var2);

var_result2 = add(var1, var2).add(var3, var4);

// etc...
```

It allows you to chain methods, and respect the usual semantics available for primitive types.

**Note:**

- Usually, the free function `operator+` would make use of the class member `operator+=` that you would define for your type, allowing also `var_result += var1`

So your final design should look like :

```
class X
{
  public:
    X& operator+=(const X& rhs) { ...; return *this; }
};

X add(X lhs, const X& rhs)
{
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```

Or if you don't want `operator+=` either (which would makes sense, at least for consistency) :

```
class X
{
  public:
    X& add(const X& rhs) { ...; return *this; }
};

X add(X lhs, const X& rhs)
{
    return lhs.add(rhs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with creating a new item, because any space/time performance costs would be *tiny* and there are serious advantages to using immutable objects.